# google database api

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to use my google account to store so data (time series)

Is there an easy way to do it?

I use R and if possible would like to create/use and API to send and receive data from/to R and from/to my google account

EDIT: I want to have an online database available from everywhere. I have thought of installing a sql server on a ftp, but that is long and a bit difficult. I want to know if there is a way to use a google account to have a database accessible from everywhere? So that I can send/receive time series from this account using standard ODBC connection for instance.

Comment: You're probably better off asking this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you explain a little better maybe we can give you some pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Microsoft and Amazon offer SQL databases in the cloud. GAE isn't an RDBMS, it's NoSQL in the cloud. If you just need an object data store, well someone has probably written a wrapper in the language you want, otherwise there's [Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/) and [Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/).

If you need an RDBMS, I suggest you check out either Microsoft's [SQL Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlazure/default.aspx) or Amazon's [Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/running_databases/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google apps](http://developer.googleapps.com/custom-dev) to create your application and store both the application and data on Google's servers. There is also the [Google Secure Data Connector](http://code.google.com/securedataconnector/) that you can use to store data on Google's servers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you discovered [Google Fusion Tables](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2571232) yet?  They are linked to your Google account, they are available from anywhere you can use Google Drive, and they come with a [Google Fusion Tables API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/).  The best part is that the API is already integrated into other tools like Google Maps and Google Charts.